# If a and b are positive integers satisfying $(a^{([2n-1]^2)}) \vert b^{([2n]^2)}$ and $b^{([2n]^2)} \vert (a^{([2n+1]^2)})$ prove a = b.

Tags: formal-proofs

Recently encountered this question:

> If a and b are positive integers satisfying $(a^{([2n-1]^2)})\ \vert \ b^{([2n]^2)}$ and $b^{([2n]^2)} \ \vert \ (a^{([2n+1]^2)})$ prove $a = b$.

My calculations so far:

Since $(a^{([2n-1]^2)})\ \vert \ b^{([2n]^2)}$ and
$b^{([2n]^2)} \ \vert \ (a^{([2n+1]^2)})$

we have that $a^{(4n^2-4n+1)}\ \vert \ a^{(4n^2+4n+1)}$, thus there exists an integer $p$ such that

$p = a^{(4n^2+4n+1)}/a^{(4n^2-4n+1)}=a^{(4n^2+4n+1-4n^2+4n-1)}=a^{(8n)}$

$4n^2\log_{(b)}/\log_{(a)}-4n^2+4n-1+4n^2+4n+1-4n^2
 \log_{(b)}/\log_{(a)}=8n$

I think they are wrong.

What should I do next? How would you attack this question (from the start, would you use my calculations)? Do you have an answer to this question? If possible, can you please explain it and show me the best way to do this?

Thanks a lot.

Edit: There has been some confusion with the question, here a photo:
[image: Photo of the above question.]

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [Mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)!!

Comment: Thanks, I edited the question.

Comment: The "for all n" phrase shouldn't be at the end. This might be a source of confusion for you.

Comment: Fixed everything.

Comment: I think there is an = sign missing. You say 'satisfying' but there is nothing to satisfy.

Comment: The two complicated expressions in $a$ and $b$: are they supposed to be equal to each other? Or to 0? Or the first to 0 and the second to 7? Etc...

Comment: https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/863422808385519627/863793481804414986/image0.jpg

Comment: I believe that by the fraction $\frac{a}{b}$ you mean that $a | b$, i.e. $a$ divides $b$. Note that the fraction notation you used in non-standard, and instead the latter notation $a \vert b$ should be used, since this is standard.

Comment: Oh, alright. Didn't know that. Extremely sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume $a>b$, then $\log_ba>1$. Choose $n\in\mathbb N$ such that $$\log_ba>\left(\frac{2n}{2n-1}\right)^2$$ which is possible since the right side tends to $1$ for $n\to\infty$. Then $$\log_ba(2n-1)^2>(2n)^2\Longrightarrow a^{(2n-1)^2}>b^{(2n)^2}$$ and thus $a^{(2n-1)^2}\nmid b^{(2n)^2}$, which is a contradiction. You can deal with the case $b>a$ in a similar way.